# Plot the eigenvalue equation for optical fibers LP modes

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fiber-optics

The eigenvalue equation for LP modes in Optical Fibers is:

$$\frac{J_{\ell - 1}(u)}{J_{\ell}(u)} = -\frac{w}{u} \frac{K_{\ell - 1}(w)}{K_{\ell}(w)}$$

where:

- $J_{\ell}(u)$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html);
- $K_{\ell}(w)$ is the [Modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html);
- $u = k_{\mathrm{core}} a$ is the normalized transverse propagation constant inside the core;
- $w = |k_{\mathrm{cladding}}| a$ is the normalized transverse propagation constant inside the cladding;
- $a$ is the radius of the fiber.

This equation can be graphically solved. But how to plot it? It includes functions of two different variables, $u$ and $w$.

In some examples, $J_{\ell - 1}(u) / J_{\ell}(u)$ is plotted using the $u$-axis as abscissa, and then the RHS is superimposed *in the same plane*. How is it possible?

---

This is so different from the dielectric slab modes, where the equations used are of the form

$$\begin{cases} w = u \tan (u)\\ v^2 = u^2 + w^2\end{cases}$$

$u$ is considered as the abscissa and $w$ the ordinate. Intersections between the two curves are easily determined.

Comment: This is a function in implicit form. A CAS can help to plot such functions.

Comment: @Jon yes, of course, but what is the abscissa and what is the ordinate? It is weird that $J_{\ell - 1}(u) / J_{\ell}(u)$ is the ordinate.

Comment: There is no difference. It is up to you and your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice about the quantities represented by the $x$ and $y$ axes is arbitrary. A convenient choice is the following one.

Rewrite the eigenvalue equation as

$$u \frac{J_{\ell - 1}(u)}{J_{\ell}(u)} = - w \frac{K_{\ell - 1}(w)}{K_{\ell}(w)}$$

Actually, the solution of this equation is the solution of the system

$$\left\{\begin{matrix} \displaystyle u \frac{J_{\ell - 1}(u)}{J_{\ell}(u)} = - w \frac{K_{\ell - 1}(w)}{K_{\ell}(w)}\\ u^2 + w^2 = v^2\end{matrix}\right.$$

In fact, $u$ and $w$ are bounded by the second equation of the system, where

$$v^2 = a^2 k_0^2 (n_1^2 - n_2^2) = a^2 \omega^2 \mu_0 \epsilon_0 (n_1^2 - n_2^2)$$

$k_0$ is the propagation constant of the current signal if it was a plain wave in the vacuum space. Note that $k_0$ is proportional to the frequency $\omega$ of this signal. $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the refractive indices (respectively) of the core and the cladding, so $n_1 > n_2$ and $v^2$ is a positive quantity.

Rewrite the second equation of the system as follows:

$$w = \sqrt{v^2 - u^2}$$

$v$ is a parameter, depending on the signal frequency $\omega$. Choose a value for it. Now, consider $u$ as the abscissa, an independent quantity.

Plot the Left Hand Side of the eigenvalue equation, which only depends on $u$. The Right Hand Side also depends only on $u$ through the relation $w = \sqrt{v^2 - u^2}$. Note, however, that (unlike the Left Hand Side) the Right Hand Side plot depends on the parameter $v$, which in turn depends on the signal frequency $\omega$. If $v$ changes, also the Right Hand Side shape will change.

Plot the Right Hand Side and evaluate the value (or values) of $u$ where an intersection between the branches of the Left Hand Side and the Right Hand Side occurs. These are the solutions of the system. In particular, the $u$ values of the intersections can be graphically determined; then, the corresponding $w = \sqrt{v^2 - u^2}$ is obtained through the second equation of the system.

If $u$ and $w$ are determined, the mode is defined.

Answer (score 2):

One example of visualization of solutions of this equation in the plane (u,w) using Mathematica 12
[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. Mathematica code to plot solution in the plane $(u,w)$

```
LPmode[l_] := 
 Module[{cp}, 
  cp = ContourPlot[
    u BesselJ[l - 1, u] BesselK[l, w] + 
      w BesselK[l - 1, w] BesselJ[l, u] == 0, {u, 0, 15}, {w, 0, 15}, 
    FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"l =", l }]]; cp]

Table[LPmode[l], {l, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: So, this is the [locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(mathematics)) defined by the implicit equation $\frac{J_{\ell - 1}(u)}{J_{\ell}(u)} + \frac{w}{u} \frac{K_{\ell - 1}(w)}{K_{\ell}(w)} = 0$ in the first quadrant of the $(u, w)$ plane, ultimately obtaining $w$ as a function of $u$?

Comment: Yes, in numerical calculations we can define `w` as function `u`  for some branches in the given region in a first quadrant of the $(u, w)$ plane.

Comment: @AlexTrounev could you tell how you solved it in Mathematica?

Comment: @Rima Please, see Update 1 to my answer.